# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', I can not add bootstrap into my vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

In my vue project `webpack.base.conf.js`:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
      'bootstrap':resolve('src/vendor/bootstrap')
    }
  },
```

I add the bootstrap resolve.

[image]

but when I import bootstrap files in the `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'  // my add line
import 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'  // my add line

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

but there get error:

[image]

```
./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' in '/Users/dele/Desktop/date/uitr_web/src'
 @ ./src/main.js 8:0-41
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you dont have css loader to handle css in your js file so

To begin, you'll need to install css-loader & style-loader:

```
npm install --save-dev css-loader style-loader
```

Then add the plugin to your webpack config. For example:

```
import 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: What's the meaning of the `i` of `test: /\.css$/i`?

Comment: Can you share your project in github  ?